# Is it "n'y rien comprendre" or "n'y comprendre rien"?

Tags: verbes, négation, ordre-des-mots, adverbes, infinitif

> [Les télégrammes fusent, les journaux s'y mettent, personne n'y
>   comprend rien.](http://bibliobs.nouvelobs.com/documents/20090713.BIB3724/l-039-ete-1914.html)

In *personne n'y comprend rien* there is, I presume, the idiom [*c'est à n'y rien comprendre*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/translate/french-english/comprendre).

If so, why is it in this context so different from its original form? Why *n'y comprend rien* instead of *n'y rien comprend*? And what about the beginning of the idiom: *c'est à*? Where has it gone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> “Être ou **ne pas être**, telle est la question”

### Generally speaking

In French, the negation of infinitive verb is different than for other tenses. The negative form of “tu es” is “tu n’es pas”, not <strike>“tu ne pas es”</strike>. With infinitive,  however, the *“ne pas”* is collected before the verb: the negative for of *“être”* is *“ne pas être”*, not <strike>*“n’être pas”*</strike>. Exceptions may apply, but in everyday speech I can’t think of any.

The negative form of “comprendre” is thus “ne pas comprendre” even though, when conjugated, the usual rules apply and the “pas” jumps behind the verb : “Je ne comprends pas”.

The same rules apply if you use *“rien”*. The correct infinitive form is *“ne rien comprendre“*, hence *“c’est à n’y rien comprendre”* ; the correct conjugated form is *“il ne comprend rien”*, which gives *“personne n’y comprend rien”*.

Mind “personne” however: *“ne connaître personne“* is correct, <strike>*“ne personne connaître"*</strike> is not.

### In this particular case

I would consider the extract *“à n’y rien comprendre”* to be idiomatic. The grammatical correctness of <strike>*“C’est à n’y comprendre rien”*</strike> could be debated, but in any case it would be *really* weird.

Comment: So in your opinion whoever wrote that piece from which I quoted this line was wrong in saying _personne n'y comprend rien_? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: _personne n'y comprend rien_ is correct. An alternative : _personne n'y comprend quoi que ce soit_

Answer (score 2):

In your example you have a subject for the verb *comprendre* so you need to conjugate it *personne n'y comprend rien*. You could have written in another sentence *personne ne comprend rien à cela* which is a sort of expanded way to say the same thing. It is not an occurrence of the idiom *c'est à n'y rien comprendre*, it is only the use of the verb *comprendre* and the contracted negative form *n'y [...] rien*.

The idiom *c'est à n'y rien comprendre* uses the infinitive form of the verb *comprendre* which does not have any subject in that case and means that you cannot understand a context or a situation.

Answer (score 1):

"c'est à n'y rien comprendre" is the Good one , "c'est à n'y comprendre rien" is Incorrect ,

this is a little Difficult what you are asking , even for me(i am from France) ,

The difference between "personne n'y comprend rien" & "c'est à n'y rien comprendre" :

"personne n'y comprend rien" mean that NOBODY(Person) is able to Understand ,

"c'est à n'y rien comprendre" mean that the SITUATION/THING is not understandable(Not a Person) , but in familiary Language , you can say for example : "C'est à n'y rien comprendre ce gars"(talking of someone , "gars" = guy)

i am not so good in grammar too , i tried to Answer your Question

Answer (score 1):

Usually when we negate verbs that are conjugated, we follow the rule “SNVP” (subject, *ne*, verb, *pas*, or in that case *rien*). *N'ouvrez pas!* (dont open).
However if we negate the INFITIVE form, the verb is always at the end. *Ne pas ouvrir!*

*N'y comprend rien* is correct.
*N'y rien comprend* is not correct. It should be *n'y rien comprenDRE* (an infinitive).

Answer (score 1):

I am a native French speaker and writer, and I'd like to add the follwing.

I would not consider "C'est à n'y comprendre rien" incorrect. French literature offers examples of this phrase as a stylistic variation of "C'est à n'y rien comprendre", both are correct.

In a famous poem of Louis Aragaon "Est-ce ainsi que les hommes vivent ?", you find the following verses:

*La pièce était-elle ou non drôle/
Moi si j'y tenais mal mon rôle/
C'était de n'y comprendre rien*

(Was the play funny or not/
Me, if I badly played my role/
It was for understanding none of it" ?)

In a song ("Un nouveau monde") from the French band "Feu! Chatterton":
"On le bégayait tous sans n'y comprendre rien".
(We all stuttered it, understanding none of if ?).

Based on these examples, both positions of "rien" are in use.